# How do I use branching in a loop in ARM Assembly?

Tags: assembly, raspberry-pi, arm

My program creates a 2d array in memory with `.skip 1000`. It then populates that array with an input from `stdin` using this loop:

```
    @@loop to store message in array
    @outer for loop over rows
    MOV r0,#0 @r0 = i (row index)
msgrowloop:
    CMP r0,r2 @compare to nrows
    BEQ msgendrowloop

    @multiply/accumulate instruction
    MLA r7, r3, r0, r6 @calculates the address of the first element in each row

    @inner for loop over columns
    MOV r1,#0 @r1 = j (column index)
msgcolumnloop:
    CMP r1,r3 @compare to ncolumns
    BEQ msgendcolumnloop

    @@@store from stdin

    PUSH {r0-r4}
    BL getchar @branch & link to getchar - reads single character from stdin

    CMP r0,#-1 @check if we're at the end of file
    BEQ msgendrowloop @if so, exit loop

    MOV r8, r0 @move character to r8
    POP {r0-r4}

    @@@store from stdin end

    @store r8 in memory and increase r7 by one byte
    STRB r8,[r7],#1
    ADD r1,r1,#1 @j += 1
    B msgcolumnloop
msgendcolumnloop:
    ADD r0,r0,#1 @i += 1
    B msgrowloop
msgendrowloop:
    @rest of the program...
```

Now, using this I get a segmentation error, but if I change my stdin function to this:

```
PUSH {r0-r4}
BL getchar @branch & link to getchar - reads single character from stdin

CMP r0, #-1 @check if we are at end of file
MOV r8, r0 @move character to r8

POP {r0-r4}
BEQ msgendrowloop @exit loop when done
```

Instead of this:

```
PUSH {r0-r4}
BL getchar @branch & link to getchar - reads single character from stdin

CMP r0,#-1 @check if we're at the end of file
BEQ msgendrowloop @if so, exit loop

MOV r8, r0 @move character to r8
POP {r0-r4}
```

It works perfectly. The logic here is confusing as my original code seems logically sound.

Comment: Where does it segfault?  Have you used a debugger to find out?  The fact that it segfaulted means that your code was *not* logically sound, of course; but equally, the fact that it no longer segfaults with your modification does not mean that you have fixed it, just that it is no longer broken in the same way...

Comment: Stack operations must be balanced. Judging by the code you've shown us, if `r0 == -1` you'll skip the `POP {r0-r4}`.

Comment: You can also solve this by only using r0-r3 for intermediates (temporaries) that don't need to be saved over function calls. Do you really need to save `R0` when calling `getchar()`?  If not, you can just use `push {r1-r4}; bl getchar; pop {r1-r4};` and `r0` is still the return status.  Otherwise, `push {r0-r4}; bl getchar; cmp r0, #-1; pop {r0-r4};`   Using r4-r8 for value to be preserved over a function call as the EABI intends solves the issue without any code.

Comment: Note also that the ARM ABI requires 8-byte stack alignment across function boundaries involving different translation units.  If you can't guarantee 8-byte alignment then you'll get undefined behaviour.  You can ensure that the stack remains 8-byte aligned by always pushing and popping even numbers of registers.

Answer (score 0):

Formalising the comments above into an answer:

The basic reason for the behaviour you're seeing is that the second form of your `stdin` function does not preserve the stack pointer (its use of the stack is not 'balanced').  The `PUSH {r0-r4}` is balanced by the `POP {r0-r4}` which restores the stack pointer to the value that it had on entry to the block, but if the `BEQ` branch is taken then the `POP` is skipped and the stack operations are no longer balanced.  That means that when another bit of code pops data from the stack, expecting to find the things it pushed there earlier, it pops the wrong values.  Most likely there is a pop involving the program counter as a function return, and it's popping a nonsense address, hence the segfault.

It is a good idea to develop skills with using a debugger to try and find the root cause of a bug like this for yourself.  Assuming that I'm right about the cause of the segfault, the basic procedure in this case would be

1. To find the line of code that generates the segfault, which probably looks something like `POP {r4-r6,pc}`
2. To establish, by taking the stack pointer from `r13` and looking at the stack in memory, that the value that's being popped into `pc` is an invalid branch address
3. To find the `PUSH {r4-r6,lr}` that balances this `POP`, and ascertain that an appropriate address was pushed in the first place
4. To notice that the stack pointer had changed in value between the end of the `PUSH` and the start of the balancing `POP` (which it should not do if all intermediate stack operations have been properly balanced)
5. To step through the code and try to find the source of the stack imbalance.

Furthermore please do pay attention to the [procedure call standard in the ARM ABI](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ihi0042f/IHI0042F_aapcs.pdf).  In a nutshell:

- `r0-r3` are used for function arguments and return values;
- `r0-r3` and `r12` are 'call-clobbered' and you can't rely on them keeping their values across function calls, so it's a good idea not to use them for intermediate storage unless you have to;
- `r4-r11` and `lr` (`r14`) are 'call-preserved' so any function you write must preserve these (but need not preserve `r0-r3` or `r12`);
- The stack should be 8-byte aligned across translation unit boundaries, so it's a good idea always to push and pop even numbers of registers to avoid falling victim to weird undefined behaviour.  Your call to `getchar` currently operates with a misaligned stack.